# Are ESRI spatial views regenerated whenever they are queried?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial, st

If a spatial view contains data "joined" from multiple tables, will all the tables be queried whenever a query is executed against the spatial view?

We have some spatial views and whenever we run a query against some of them, the query can take over an hour to run. We're talking about a basic "select * from xyz" query.

Update - We are not using versioning and the geometry is stored as st_geometry.

Comment: what RDBMS are you using, what spatial type are you using and is your data versioned?

Comment: A view is a cached query, but only the *rule* is cached, not the results.  Full table scan query performance is all about join indexes (and optimizer hints, as necessary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes. A view is basically a stored query.

A couple of general things you can try to speed up you database performance.

1. Make sure all your join fields are indexed
2. Make sure the database statistics are refreshed
3. If you data is versioned are you using ESRI multi versioned views as part of you views?
4. If your data is versioned make sure you run a compress and analyze regularly

**Edit**

5. Also try dropping and recreating the spatial indexes on the geometry columns